# Hibernate insert after save

Tags: java, hibernate

In my realization I have something like

```
public void insert(String type )
    Session s= dao.getCurrentSession();
    Long id=dao.getId();
    s.createQuery("insert into table1 t (id,msg,(select t2.typeId from table2 t2 where type =?)) VALUES (?,?,?)")
        .setParameter(0, id,       Hibernate.Long)
        .setParameter(1, "msg",    Hibernate.String)
        .setParameter(2, type,     Hibernate.String)
        .executeUpdate();
}
```

I want to change that to

```
public void insert(String type)
    Session s= dao.getCurrentSession();
    Long id=dao.getId();
    Long typeId=null;
    typeId=(Long)s.createQuery("select t2.type from table2 t2 where type =?").
            .setParameter(0, type,  Hibernate.String)
            .uniqueResult();

    if(typeId==null){
       Table2 t=new Table2(type);
       typeId=(Long)s.save(t);
    }
    s.createQuery("insert into table1 t (id,msg,Table2")) VALUES (?,?,?)
        .setParameter(0, id,      Hibernate.Long)
        .setParameter(1, "msg",   Hibernate.String)
        .setParameter(2, typeId,  Hibernate.Long)
        .executeUpdate();
}
```

After that manipulation I get exception about constraint because I haven't new `type`with `typeId` in `table2`, however, in Debug mode in IDEA I can see, that `typeId=s.save(t);` return new `id` from insert. My id generates with Sequence in oracle.

If I add `Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction()` and `tx.commit()`, so I get new exception, that Session closed and it is not possible to make insert.

How to avoid that?

P.S-----------------

My table2 is

```
 public class Table2 implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6213740208940441112L;
  private Long typeId = null;
  private String type;

  public Table2 () {
  }

  public Table2 (String type) {
  this.type=type;
  }

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator( name = "table_type", sequenceName = "seq_table_type", allocationSize = 1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "table_type")
  public Long getTypeId() {
    return this.typeId;
  }
  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
  @NotNull
  public String getType() {
    return this.type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type= type;
  }
```

Comment: instead of '''save''' try using makePersistence() method.

Comment: Please show us the native SQL which are you trying to run.  It is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, what do you mean? My native query is `insert into table1 t (id,msg,(select t2.typeId from table2 t2 where type =?)) VALUES (?,?,?)` instead of `?` you can put 10,"text",43.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal, thank you for advice. Next 2 hours I try it.

Comment: @RahulAgrawal, but s.persist doesn't return any value, so Do I need to make the second query to get my new typeId? and after that in third query I do insert? 
Anyway I've tried with `s.persist(new Table2(type));` and `typeId=s.("select t2.type from table2 t2 where typeId =?").
            .setParameter(0, type,  Hibernate.String)
            .uniqueResult();` return null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some realization

```
public void insert(String type)
    Session s= dao.getCurrentSession();
    Long id=dao.getId();
    Long typeId=(Long)s.createQuery("select typeId from table2 where type =?").
            .setParameter(0, type,  Hibernate.String)
            .uniqueResult();

    if(typeId==null){
       Table2 t=new Table2(type);
       typeId=(Long)s.save(t);
       s.flush();
    }
    s.createQuery("insert into table1 t (id,msg,Table2")) VALUES (?,?,?)
        .setParameter(0, id,      Hibernate.Long)
        .setParameter(1, "msg",   Hibernate.String)
        .setParameter(2, typeId,  Hibernate.Long)
        .executeUpdate();
        s.flush();
}
```

But now, I can't rollback any changing if I'd get any exception even If i do something like this

```
 ...
} catch (Throwable e) {
        s.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

And it happens because of Oracle's sequence can't make rollback.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you change value of Long named typeId, but in your insert you still use your incoming String attribute named type.

Try to change your incoming type or use created typeId in your insert.

Comment: and where is the answer?It's only our suggestion, which you could write in comments. Delete that post, please

Comment: I cannot write to question comments and the answer is that you use a different variable in your code - that is the reason why your second code is not working. I've made minor changes to my post. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: Ok, it was mistake in question, not in realization in my Program

Comment: OK, thanks for explanation. Now I would suggest changing `("insert into table1 t (id,msg,Table2")) VALUES (?,?,?)` to `("insert into table1 t (id,msg,typeId)) VALUES (?,?,?)"`

Comment: It is correct. because I have Fetch for third column with Table1